# calling multiple servlets from android client

Tags: android, servlet-3.0, urlconnection

I am calling a servlet on application load and another servlet on button click in android through url connection.It is connecting to the servlet on application load but not connecting to the servlet on button click.What can be the reason?

Comment: Post ur code there might be something wrong

Comment: Reasons could be many. Any chance we could take a look at your code?